# custom dynamic table in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ui-components

I am working on the dynamic custom table, the table header and its corresponding data needs to be changed.

The structure of the data

```
{
  type:"table1",
  headers:["h1", "h2", "h3"],
  columns:[
    ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3"],
    ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3"],
    ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3"],
    ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3"]
  ]
},
{
  type:"table2",
  headers:["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4"],
  columns:[
    ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3", "cell4"],
    ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3", "cell4"],
    ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3", "cell4"],
    ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3", "cell4"]
  ]
}
```

I have five links from the left side as menu. Based on the five link the table header will change